# Can't install php 5.6

Tags: php, vps, centos7

```
root@host [~]# yum install php56w php56w-opcache
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: denver.gaminghost.co
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
 * extras: chicago.gaminghost.co
 * updates: centos.vwtonline.net
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
No package php56w available.
No package php56w-opcache available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

This what i get from trying to install php 5.6, also - i can't install PHP mbstring extension.

What can I do ?

BTW it's debian 8

Comment: possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/732468/how-to-install-php56-on-centos-6-x86-64

Comment: In Debian you should use `aptitude` to install packages.

Comment: Why have you tagged this CentOS7, if you're stating it's Debian 8? Also, yum actually is used on CentOS7, which makes this even more confusing. Please tidy up your question, it's incredibly unclear right now.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am also install PHP 5.6 in My System.The Installation is  Successfully Completed.Please Follow the below step -

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below link to install php mysql and phpmyadmin.
[Click Here to get file](https://github.com/urshitrsheth/phpmysql)

Steps for install php,mysql and phpmyadmin

1. Go to the folder which you have downloaded the file.
2. use command as below

   **sudo ./phpserverInstallation.sh**

it will automatically install php mysql and phpmyadmin.